# Justifying an equality involving a closed operator $A$

Tags: operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

> Justify the equality $$A \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda t} S(t) u \, dt = \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda t} AS(t) u \, dt$$ used in (16) of §7.4.1. (Hint: Approximate the integral by a Riemann sum and recall $A$ is a closed operator.)

PDE by Evans, 2nd edition: Chapter 7, Exercise 13

The properties of $A$ being a closed operator are outlined in this remark on page 436:

> **Remark.** To say $A$ is *closed* means that whenever $u_k \in D(A)$ ($k=1,\ldots$) and $u_k \to u$, $Au_k \to v$ as $k \to \infty$, then $$u \in D(A), \quad v = Au.$$

Now, when I tried recalling the Riemann sum definitions for both expressions, I am probably supposed to show that
$$A \sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-\lambda t_k^*} S(t_k^*) u \Delta t = \sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-\lambda t_k^*} AS(t_k^*) u \Delta t $$
But how can I use the properties of the *closed* operator $A$ to justify this equality?

Comment: I suppose $u \in D(A)$...? Do you know that $u \in D(A) \implies S_t u \in D(A)$ for all $t \geq 0$?

Comment: Yes, $u \in D(A)$, as per the remark copied from the textbook that I wrote above. And yes to your second question; that was stated in the textbook, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set

$$u_k := \sum_{j=1}^k e^{-\lambda t_j^*} S(t_j^*)u \Delta t.$$

Since $u \in D(A)$ implies $S_t u \in D(A)$ for any $t \geq 0$, we have $u_k \in D(A)$. Moreover, by the linearity of $A$,

$$Au_k = \sum_{j=1}^k e^{-\lambda t_j^*} AS(t_j^*)u \Delta t.$$

Moreover, we know that $u_k$ converges to

$$u := \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\lambda t} S(t) u \, dt.$$

Exactly the same reasoning shows that

$$Au_k \to v:= \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\lambda t} A S(t) u \, dt.$$

As $A$ is a closed operator, it follows that $Au = v$, i.e.

$$A \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\lambda t} S(t) u \, dt = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\lambda t} A S(t) u \, dt.$$

Comment: I'm reading your answer again, but I'm not sure how the statement "$u \in D(A)$ implies $S(t)u \in D(A)$" is enough to justify $u_k \in D(A)$.

Comment: @dragon Why? since $A$ is a linear opertor, we know that $\lambda v + \mu w \in D(A)$ for any $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{R}$ whenever $v,w \in D(A)$.